# What does "in the ground" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *F9 (2021)*, Buddy says to Dom about Jakob:

> Buddy: You've got people who love you, count on you, care for you. He
> ain't got no one. You get in his way, this ain't gonna end until one
> of you guys are **in the ground**.

What does "in the ground" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this ain't gonna end until one of you guys are in the ground.

means this:

> this ain't gonna end until one of you guys are dead and buried.

Native speakers understand **in the ground** to mean something like `under the surface and surrounded by dirt.` And of course a person could not survive such a situation for more than a few moments. Burial after death is the most common way of being **in the ground**.

To distinguish the idea from similar situations, we use phrases like these:

> **one of you is in a hole** `a hole exists and you are in it; an opening is above you`
> **one of you is in the dirt** `there is some loose soil on the surface and you are lying/standing/crawling in it`

I don't know about other native speakers, but I am most familiar with this usage of **in the ground** from crime stories in print and on the screen. The speaker is usually a tough guy: criminal, detective, etc.